# Rails 3 and jQuery Datepicker

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

i need advice about my problem, i use jquery ui DatePicker, 
this work really good in my rails problem, but  in the form i use with this jquery, i have a white row appear at the end of the page. When i select the field with Datepicker and choose a date, the white row disappears.

my jquery are like this

```
jQuery(function() {
   $(".showcal").datepicker({showOn:'both'});
}
```

my form have a text_field

```
<%= f.text_fields :first_date, :class => showcal %>
```

I use jQuery min 1.6.2
My Layout head

```
  <head>
    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Cadifice" %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css", "application" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "jquery.fancybox-1.3.4", "application" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "jquery.highlight-3", "application" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'bottom' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>

<%= javascript_include_tag "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.15/jquery-ui.min.js", "application" %> 
<%= javascript_include_tag 'pikachoose', 'jquery.pikachoose.full' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'cadifice', 'jquery.cadifice' %>

    <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
    <%= yield(:head) %>
  </head>
```

thanks

Comment: Are you also loading Prototype? (that's the javascript library that comes bundled with RoR and is loaded by default).

Comment: I don't hink, nothing in Gemfile and i have edited my question with my default layout.

Comment: It's normally included with "<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>" - I would take a look at the source for one of your pages and see if its showing up in the application.js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also encounter that problem every now and then. For some reason (bug?) the datepicker panel sometimes does not get hidden. A simple workaround is add one more line to hide it yourself after initialising the datepickers. For exmaple,

```
$(".showcal").datepicker({showOn:'both'});
$('#ui-datepicker-div').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are loading Prototype per my comments on your question, take a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443844/rails-3-fancybox/7556963#7556963) to another question involving RoR and jQuery. It resolved that person's issues.